# Understanding Example of Change of Basis Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

The following theorem has been stated in Friedberg (4th edition) Linear Algebra book:

Theorem 2.22. Let $\beta$ and $\beta^{\prime}$ be two ordered bases for a finite-dimensional
vector space V, and let $\text{Q} = {[I_{V}]}^{\beta}_{\beta}{\prime}$. Then

a) $\text{Q}$ is invertible.

b) For any $\text{v}$ $\epsilon$ $\text{V}$, ${[v]}_{\beta}$ = $\text{Q}{[v]}_{\beta}{\prime}$.

I understood this theorem.

The problem I'm facing is while reconciling the `(b)` of this theorem with the following example.

`Example:` In $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\beta$ = {(1, 1), (1, −1)} and ${\beta}^{\prime}$ = {(2, 4), (3, 1)}. Since
(2, 4) = 3(1, 1) − 1(1, −1) and (3, 1) = 2(1, 1) + 1(1, −1),
the matrix that changes ${\beta}^{\prime}$-coordinates into $\beta$-coordinates is $\text{Q}$

\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}

The process of creating the matrix, I'm clear. But section `b` of theorem says, (1,1) = $\text{Q}$ * (2,4). But that's not the case.

Can someone please tell me where I'm making mistake in my undersatnding?

Thanks!

Comment: "But section b of theorem says, (1,1) = Q * (2,4)." - could you elaborate on why you say this?

Comment: Note that if $v = (2, 4)$ then $[v]_{\beta'} = (1, 0)$. Then $Q[v]_{\beta'} = (3, -1)$, which is $v$ expressed in terms of the basis $\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not interpreting the statement correctly. Take, say $v=(1,0)$. Then$$[v]_\beta=\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\quad\text{and}\quad[v]_{\beta'}=\left(-\frac1{10},\frac25\right).$$What (b) claims is that $[v]_\beta=Q[v]_{\beta'}$; in other words,$$\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)=\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\left(-\frac1{10},\frac25\right),$$and you can check that this is indeed true.

Comment: This make sense! Thanks Jose!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.